# How to overriding protocol scheme handler (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, protocol-handler

I need to override standard protocol handler for my VoIP desktop software. There are MS instruction about protocol handler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)

But in reality this instruction allow to create new handlers, yes - this is working, but I need exactly to override existing handlers. For example, if I creating protocol handler "test", all working fine and my software handle that protocol. However if I try to override protocol "sip" any browser in my computer still try to call Skype, instead my own program.

[image: Skype]

I don't understand what happens, my Registry has no reference to Skype at all. Any idea?